# Selecting a specific link that has the same name

Tags: jquery

I'm a total beginner with any kind of scripting so sorry if this is a dumb question. What I am trying to do is open 2 links from a webpage on page load . Both links have the same name and I am trying to split them up . I can get them to console log the links but can not seam to figure out how to open them with a window.open

```
$('p.place.bg-dark span a').each(function(index, value){
    var ihref = $(this).attr('href');
    if (ihref.indexOf("http") >= 0) 
    {
        console.log(ihref);
        var link1 = (ihref ?);
        var link2 = (ihref ?);            
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlow.  When asking a question, its a good idea to paste any relevant code and things you've done already. Your question as asked is unanswerable.

Comment: Sorry about the code Issue, That is basically all i have so far.

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well?

Comment: what are you trying to do with link1 and link2 ???

Comment: did you try `window.open(ihref)` ?

Comment: where is your code to open the window?

Comment: <p class="place bg-dark">
             <span><b>Company</b>: example</span>
              <span><b>City</b>: </span>
              <span><b>State</b>: </span>
              <span><b>Full address</b>: 1234 any st</span>
              <span><b>URL (right-click to open in separate browswer)</b>: <a href="http://www.example.com.com/">http://www.example.com/</a></span>
 </p>

Comment: sorry I'm new to the site so I keep messing up the formatting    here is the window.open part                                                                                              var w = screen.availWidth/2;
    var h = screen.availHeight;


var myWindow1 = window.open(link1, 'Win 1', 'width='+w+', height='+h+', scrollbars=yes, toolbar=yes');
});


var myWindow2 = window.open(link2, 'Win 2', 'width='+w+', height='+h+', scrollbars=yes, toolbar=yes');
});

Comment: yes I tried the window.open(iherf) that works for opening the first link on the page. There are actually two per page that is where I'm running into trouble trying to make link1 a var and link2 a var so i can open both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong, there was no reason to use the each function all i had to do was get the link by :eq . Thanks for the replies they sent me in the right direction.

```
var link1= $('p.place.bg-dark span a:eq(0)').attr('href');
var link2= $('p.place.bg-dark span a:eq(1)').attr('href');
var w = screen.availWidth/2;
var h = screen.availHeight;
var mywindow1=window.open(link2,'2', 'width='+w+', height='+h+',  scrollbars=yes, toolbar=yes');
var w = screen.availWidth/2;
var h = screen.availHeight;
var mywindow2=window.open(link1,'1', 'width='+w+', height='+h+', scrollbars=yes, toolbar=yes');
```